# HP laptop wireless network problem

Tags: wifi, laptop

I have a fairly new HP Compaq 6715b laptop.  It is running Windows Vista Business 64-bit with the latest drivers and HP updates for the Broadcom network adaptor.

My problem is that I can only get the wireless networking to detect networks when I am very close to the wireless access point (within about 5 meters).

I have the same problem when connecting to the wireless network at work, at home and in public areas, so I don't think the issue is with the access points.

At home I have an older laptop and Nintendo Wii that can both see and connect to the wireless network at distances far greater than my HP laptop, so again, I think this points to a problem with the laptop itself.

What I have noticed is that the wireless network strength is only ever reported as Excellent, I can't even see networks with a lower strength.

Has anyone seen this problem before, and does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see on the 'net, it looks like that laptop has PCIe slots, so you should open it up and make sure that your antennas are actually connected to your PCIe wireless card - the connectors are tiny, and sometimes a bit "fiddly" so they could have jarred loose or somesuch.  Failing that, it sounds like it might be time to test out your warranty.

Comment: Be aware that if it is under warranty still, doing so is likely to void your warranty.

Comment: Really? I thought PCIe cards were considered 'user servicable' - I'm fairly sure Dell considers them so.

Comment: @pdz, it may depend on how much effort is required to get at the card. On Dells they are usually accessible via a little panel on the bottom. On a Hp Mini Netbook I had to literally dismantle the whole thing to access the back of the motherboard where the wifi card is mounted

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a fault with the wireless network card in your laptop. Has it always been like this, or has it degraded over time? If its still in warranty I would get it looked at by HP and repaired.